# Using wildcards in the title operator

Tags: support, search

I'm trying to  trying to get [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then) to show up in the search and I searched for title:which* and it is not turning up. Needless to say, title:which and title:*which* doesn't work either although the latter works literally which suggests that the wildcards don't work in titles? Is there a way to get them to work?

Answer (score 6):

In my trials, wildcards simply do not work when using `title:`. For a demonstration try searching for `title:char*cter`.

This appears to be an issue that's been known about for at least a year. I found this meta highlighting the exact same issue as yourself.

- [Allow wildcard in title search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195083/allow-wildcard-in-title-search)

You can also go directly to the API and use this page to query the site directly, but it will fail in the same way, mainly in that `title:` simply cannot handle wildcards, only literal strings.

- [result searching for "Why not use"](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&title=why%20not%20use&filter=default&site=unix&run=true)

#### Alternatives

I generally don't use the SE search unless I'm looking for something specific that I know I wrote up or Gilles, or some other user by name. So I often do `user:me`, `user:885`, or `user:22565`. I'll occasionally use our tags, but more times than not I'm using Google.

In your case, searching for that `which` question:

- [site:unix.stackexchange.com "which*"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com%20%22which*%22&oq=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com%20%22which*%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.11877j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Shows it as the 7th result. If you can remember "not use which" you can get it as the 1st result:

- [site:unix.stackexchange.com "not use which"](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&es_sm=93&q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com%20%22not%20use%20which%22&oq=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com%20%22not%20use%20which%22&gs_l=serp.3...44411.46534.0.47452.10.9.1.0.0.0.96.672.8.8.0.msedrc...0...1c.1.58.serp..10.0.0.NTyeNlQ_Ktg)

Comment: I can never remember 885, let alone 22565… I do try to link commonly-used reference questions in the relevant tag wiki.

Comment: @Gilles - I know! I have a cheat sheet for a couple of us that I know provide answers to Q's I've needed to dig up and couldn't find them easily via search. I just recently noticed you (or others) had been including key Q&A in the tag wiki as well. That's a good place to store them, but will probably go unnoticed by newer users.

Answer (score 2):

The word `which` is in quotes in the title: . I think there's some oddity (quite possibly a bug) where the indexer stores `"which"` (including the quotes) but the search query parser strips punctuation and passes `which` with no quotes to the backend. Wildcards don't help because they can't be combined with the `title:` operator.

I would edit the quotes out of the title, except that because “which” is a syntactically highly meaningful word in English, it would make the sentence hard to parse.

The easiest way to find this question is to navigate to the [which](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/which) tag, which you can reach by typing `[which]` as a search query. That question is the top-voted one.

The question is also linked from the [which](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/which) tag wiki.